# Swapping string elements in each row of a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following script:

```
import pandas as pd

gdf = pd.read_csv('Geolocation_main')
print gdf['Geolocation'][:5]
```

Which outputs:

```
0    (50.673675, -120.298973)
1    (50.678354, -120.329258)
2    (50.672496, -120.333317)
3    (50.673359, -120.332912)
4     (50.673411, -120.32978)

print type(gdf['Geolocation'][0])
<type 'str'>
```

I need to swap the geo coordinates in each cell e.g. (-120.298973,50.673675).

For that I wrote the following script:

```
correct = []

for u in gdf['Geolocation']:
    u = u.replace('(', '')
    u = u.replace(')', '')
    a, b = u.split(',')
    correct = b, a
    gdf['Geolocation_correct'] = correct
    print gdf['Geolocation_correct']
```

But its giving me a mistake. ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: please report the 'mistake' you get

Comment: `correct = gdf['Geolocation_correct']` shouldn't this be the other way?

Comment: @joaquin KeyError: 'Geolocation_correct'

Comment: @Van Peer, sorry, it was the other way round initially, the mistake I am getting is ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: @user4718221 ok. please show sample csv content. there might be a better way instead of replacing after creating the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error you get is because of

```
correct = gdf['Geolocation_correct']
```

`gdf['Geolocation_correct']` is not defined there.

You can do:

```
def fix_geo_location( u):
    u = u.replace('(', '')
    u = u.replace(')', '')
    a, b = u.split(',')
    correct = "(%s,%s)" %(b,a)
    return correct

df["Geolocation_correct"] = df["Geolocation"].map( fix_geo_location)
```

Comment: Its giving me the following error ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: It works for me. I think this is more readable than other answers

Comment: @user4718221 I cannot see the source of this error, maybe you could print more data from `gdf["Geolocation"]`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this as well:

```
>>> df['Geolocation'].map(lambda a: str(tuple(map(float, a.strip('()').split(',')))[::-1]))
0    (-120.298973, 50.673675)
1    (-120.329258, 50.678354)
2    (-120.333317, 50.672496)
3    (-120.332912, 50.673359)
4     (-120.32978, 50.673411)
Name: Geolocation, dtype: object
```